# Allow WAN to LAN traffic

Tags: sonicwall

Sonicwall NSA-240 - Fully patched and updated.

X0=LAN             192.168.1.0 (primary site)

X1-WAN1            10.10.10.2

X2-WAN2            70.151.12.10

X1-WAN1            192.168.100.0  (secondary site)

I now have a new ATT MPLS circuit on WAN1. Traffic from our secondary site that is destined for our X0 subnet is routed over WAN1 via ATT cloud based firewall.

I need to allow all traffic from 192.168.100.0 on WAN1 access to the LAN.

I am thinking transparent or L2 bridge mode?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are there two X1 interfaces?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need transparent mode.  Your firewall will forward traffic from the WAN1 to the LAN interfaces, assuming your policies allow it. To configure these policies, you will need to create firewall rules for the LAN to WAN and also be sure to add routes to this firewall and the firewall at your secondary site for 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 (respectively) so that traffic will route through the correct gateway.